# If i resize the browser vertically, footer and content are shifted up

Tags: javascript, html, css

If i resize the browser vertically, footer and content are shifted up but if i do the same in another page of my website, this don't happen. It happens only if i have a div with id 'hero'.

In a page i have only a div with id 'poster' and all is fine, when i resize the browser vertically, all the contents are cutted off, as i want.

In a page i have a div with id 'hero' and when i resize the browser vertically, the footer and the contents are shifted up.

I put some images:

[Right one page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Bwz.png)

[Second page with right layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/713Up.jpg)

Now i have resized the browser vertically:

[Second page with bad layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkYOY.png)

I think it's a problem by the CSS, so i'll give you the CSS:

```
#hero, #heroEventi {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 92%;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.9)), url('../img/bg-hero.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#heroEventi {
    min-width: 620px;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url('../img/bg-eventi.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#hero__content, #heroEventi__content {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#heroEventi {
    height: 53%;
}


#poster {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

#poster__img {
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
}

#poster__img img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#poster__content {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 35%;
    padding: 50px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#poster__content h3 {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#posterhero, #posterheroContatti {
    display: flex;
    padding: 100px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), url('../img/bg-aboutus.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#posterheroContatti {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), url('../img/bg-contacts.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#posterherotitle {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#posterhero__text {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-right: 10%;
}
```

HTML of bad page:

```
<div id="heroEventi">
            <div id="heroEventi__content">
                <h1>Eventi</h1>
                <div id="searchBar">
                    <h2> Ricerca degli eventi </h2>
                    <div id="flexSearch">
                        <div id="customSelectCat">
                            <?php
                                if(isset($_SESSION['option'])){
                                    echo $_SESSION['option'];
                                    unset($_SESSION['option']);
                                } else {
                            ?>
                                    <select id="listCat">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Seleziona la categoria</option>
                                        <option value="Concerti">Concerti</option>
                                        <option value="Sport">Sport</option>
                                        <option value="MostreEMusei">Mostre e Musei</option>
                                        <option value="Teatro">Teatro</option>
                                    </select>
                            <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                            <span id="customArrowCat"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="customSelectSotCat">
                            <select id="listSotCat">
                            </select>
                            <span id="customArrowSotCat"></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="date" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" onkeydown="return false">
                        <input type="date" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" onkeydown="return false">
                        <button id="cerca">Cerca</button><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

HTML of right page:

```
<div id="posterheroContatti">
            <div id="posterherotitle">
                <h3>Contatti</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="posterhero__text">
                <h4>Informazioni sugli eventi</h4>
                <p>Sei un navigatore DailyTicket? Desideri maggiori informazioni sugli eventi che ti interessano?<br>Chiama il call center al numero 000.111. (Il costo della chiamata da rete fissa è di 1 euro al minuto senza scatto alla risposta.  Il costo massimo del servizio da rete mobile è di 1 euro e 50 centesimi al minuto con scatto alla risposta di 12,91 centesimi.)</p>
                <h4>Partnership e iniziative Marketing</h4>
                <p>Sei un’azienda o un’istituzione che vuole sviluppare una partnership o un’iniziativa di co-marketing? DailyTicket prenderà in considerazione le tue esigenze ed effettuerà un analisi approfondita. Scrivi a: <a href= "mailto:marketing@dailyticket.it">marketing@dailyticket.it</a></p>
                <h4>Lavora con noi</h4>
                <p>
                Vuoi lavorare con TicketOne? Sei alla ricerca di uno stage? <br>Scrivi a: <a href="mailto:lavoraconnoi@dailyticket.it">lavoraconnoi@dailyticket.it</a><br>
                Vi ricordiamo che verranno prese in considerazione solo le candidature inviate all'indirizzo mail sopra indicato, i curricula spediti a qualsiasi altro indirizzo mail non verranno letti.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide your HTML of the bad page as well?

Comment: Hi, I just edited the question with the HTML of bad page and right page, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your height in `#heroEventi` to `height: 100vh;`

```
#heroEventi {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

It seems your "correct" page has a height of 100vh associated with it.

1 other thing I saw incase changing the height doesn't work is to add `padding: 100px 0;` to `#heroEventi`  As it seems your correct page has a padding and your bad page doesn't.  So this could also be the issue.

```
#heroEventi {
    height: 53%;
    padding: 100px 0;
}
```

Comment: @BlowLore I just updated my answer with a second possible solution regarding padding. Please look at my answer again.

Comment: @BlowLore is this website live? If so can you link it? I might be able to get some more clues from actual page with the problem

Comment: unfortunately not, i'm working in localhost, if u want i can share with you my screen with teamviewer?

Comment: @BlowLore I don't have teamviewer and I don't want to download it.  Are you able to make a codepen with a lot more of your site code in it?  For instance having code with your actual footer in it where the issue is happening?

Comment: Wait, i have eliminated some heightin heroEventi__content and seems to work, i'm doing some tests.
By the way, my website is in php, i don't know how to load that, i'm just doing a project for my university

Comment: @BlowLore ok good you got it working.  btw, you didn't provide the CSS code for `heroEventi__content` so I wasn't able to see that.